# VBA Getting Object from Multiple Open Instances of Attachmate?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way how to see how many windows are open when selecting from an existing window? I have the following code but it will pretty much only select the last window that was opened.

```
Dim App As Attachmate_Reflection_Objects_Framework.ApplicationObject
Dim screen As Attachmate_Reflection_Objects_Emulation_IbmHosts.IbmScreen
Dim Terminal As Attachmate_Reflection_Objects_Emulation_IbmHosts.IbmTerminal
Dim Frame As Attachmate_Reflection_Objects.Frame
Dim View As Attachmate_Reflection_Objects.View


Set App = GetObject(, "Attachmate_Reflection_Objects_Framework.ApplicationObject"
```

Comment: If you can add the dll/object into VBE References, you can browse what is available.

Comment: Maybe something like this would be useful (assuming you can modify it to work with your specific application)  http://www.northatlantawebdesign.com/index.php/2009/07/14/getting-the-com-object-from-hwnd-using-accessibleobjectfromwindow-in-microsoft-word-2007/